# Lumen: Uploading a file / Disk does not have a configured driver

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, flysystem

Lumen 6.3.4 / PHP 7.3.9

Trying to upload a file from form data. Getting this error: `Disk [qr_uploads] does not have a configured driver.`

**bootstrap/app.php**

```
$app->configure('filesystems');
$app->register(Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class);
```

**config/filesystems.php**

```
<?php

return [
    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
        'permissions' => [
            'file' => [
                'public' => 0664,
                'private' => 0600,
            ],
            'dir' => [
                'public' => 0775,
                'private' => 0700,
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'qr_uploads' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('qr_uploads'),
        'permissions' => [
            'file' => [
                'public' => 0664,
                'private' => 0600,
            ],
            'dir' => [
                'public' => 0775,
                'private' => 0700,
            ],
        ],
    ]
];
```

**controller.php**

```
$upFile = $request->file('uploading');    
$storedPath = $upFile->store('e_'.$entityId, 'qr_uploads');
```

Getting the aforementioned error. Directory `app/storage/qr_uploads` exists and is writable. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Laravel/Lumen docs are too fizzy about the configuration file. The correct **config/filesystems.php** file should include "disks" property:

```
<?php

return [
    'disks' => [
        'local' => [...]
]
```

That's one thing. The other thing related to Lumen (I am not sure about Laravel) - you have to install the Flysystem dependency explicitly!

```
composer require league/flysystem
```

Sometime I really wish Lumen/Laravel docs were somewhat specific with the details like this. :/